# Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input in 'utf8towcs' using ore.pull()

Tags: r, oracle, utf-8

I am trying to read data from database using `ore.pull()` and get 
*Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input 'Время работы' in 'utf8towcs'*

'`Время работы`' is a value of the table. The other table, including russian text, is red with no warnings.

```
When I try to use such as construction:

data<-ore.doEval(function(){
    library(ORE)
    ore.connect(user="rquser", sid="testmcod", host="", password="rquser", port=1521, all=FALSE)
    ore.sync(table = c("C_REPORT_VALUES"))
    ore.attach()   
    ore.pull(C_REPORT_VALUES)
  })
```

, I get the following result: `<c2><f0><e5><ec><ff> <f0><e0><e1><ee><f2><fb>`
which is char containing '`Время работы`'

Any ideas to this problem? Thanks.